# Is it possible to display current workflows on the welcome page of a doc set?

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-set

I would like to have the workflows active for a particular doc set shown on the welcome page so that when a user clicks on the link for the doc set in the email they get they will see the task instead of having to go to the workflow tasks page.  I thought I could do this by adding a list view of the Workflow tasks and setting a filter only showing the tasks for that doc set by linking the related content column with the name of the doc set but for some reason filtering based on the name of the doc set is not an option, just filtering by the other categories. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible creating a list view in the Documents Library with the workflow related column, filtered by workflow status. This column will display a link for a page, listing the tasks.
It's necessary add a step in the workflow to change your status when it's finished (to filter by this).

Comment: I cant customize my workflows because I don't have SharePoint Designer.  Is there any other way?

Comment: It's complicated, because you need a info to use as a filter. Your current workflow change a document info when completed?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure. I realized the Title column works instead of the name column but the issue is that connecting it with the related content column in the workflow doesn't work since that is a lookup column.  I'm thinking if I could somehow just display the workflow status column in my doc set that would be ideal but it doesn't look like that column is available outside the doc library.

Comment: Unfortunately, that column is available only in the doc library.